# Check if notification LED exists on device and which colors are available

Tags: android, android-notifications, led

I've implemented red LED light for my notifications for test purposes, but...

Do I have to check if the device has LED (in case that device doesn't have this feature) and if so how to do it? Also, are LED colors predetermined?

I tried to find some docs or thread that would give me an answer for these questions but had no luck...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I detect the presence/absence of 'LED notification' on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997692/can-i-detect-the-presence-absence-of-led-notification-on-an-android-device)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of doing this.

According to [Can I detect the presence/absence of 'LED notification' on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997692/can-i-detect-the-presence-absence-of-led-notification-on-an-android-device)

Most hardware features are exposed via the package manager:

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity ().getPackageManager ();
boolean hasBluetooth =  pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
```

But not this one.

There is a feature request on record as well:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38481

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check the availability of the LED. the code won't crash even if there is no LED. you can set any color as a hexadecimal color code.

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification .ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
notification .flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```